# addListenerForSingleValueEvent is not executing

Tags: android, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

addListenerForSingleValueEvent is not executing at all. While running the debugger, it is not fetching the data from the database. I have even tried addValueEventListener, but of no use.

I have added the code for fragment on which I am trying to execute this.

```
package com.example.visan.peds;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class Landing_mother extends Fragment {

    private List<Ailment> ailments;

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;

    public Landing_mother(){}

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_landing_mother,container,false);

        ailments=new ArrayList<>();

        recyclerView =(RecyclerView)view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView1);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        layoutManager=new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        getData();

        adapter=new LandingAdapter(ailments,getActivity());

        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        return view;
    }

    private void getData(){
        FirebaseDatabase db=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        DatabaseReference ref=db.getReference().child("Mother");

        if(ref!=null){
            ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    if (dataSnapshot.exists()){
                        Ailment ailment=new Ailment();
                        for (int i=0;i<dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount();i++){
                            String img=dataSnapshot.child(Integer.toString(i)).child("img").getValue(String.class);
                            ailment.setImage_url(img);
                            String name=dataSnapshot.child(Integer.toString(i)).child("name").getValue(String.class);
                            ailment.setName(name);
                            ailments.add(ailment);
                        }
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
        }else {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Reference not obtained",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please note that onDataChange is not part of your main flow. You call getData() and assume that the values are being retrieved from the database immediately, after which you set the adapter. But in reality, the onDataChange is probably firing later. Try using setadapter or notifydatasethaschanged within the onDataChange method.